# URL not opening on button click

Tags: java, android

I'm pretty new on the Android development, and I'm starting my first application.

I faced my first problem on the development, and the problem is "when clicking a button, the URL doesn't open, instead of that the app crashes." .

This is MainActivity.java:

```
package com.rodentsmobile.app;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.media.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.security.*;
import android.system.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void ViewAptoide(View v)
    {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Firstly, it was `public void ViewAptoide()` but I thought that's forgetting the `View v` is the reason of the app crashing and not opening the URL.. But that wasn't the reason.

However, here is main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="300px"
        android:layout_width="700px"
        android:src="@drawable/image_1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/mainImageView1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rodents Mobile"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainImageView1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/mainTextView1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Aptoide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainTextView1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="viewAptoide"
        android:translationY="15dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: please provide your crash log

Comment: @r4jiv007 - How to view it? in which directory of the app/android system?

Comment: Where is your webview

Comment: use logcat to get the logs , google about how to use logcat in android studio. @RanjanDas I don't think webview is required here

Comment: @r4jiv007 - I'm not using Android Studio.

Comment: try running adb logcat command from terminal or command prompt , if you are using eclipse , u can also use logcat in it

Comment: then please provide  your log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In xml you have used

```
android:onClick="viewAptoide " .
```

And in activity you used

```
 public void ViewAptoide (View v)
    {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Replace it with

```
 public void viewAptoide (View v)
    {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Check xml on click name and method name should be same.

Comment: Exactly as I was going to say!  Nice answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! the problem is fixed now, I didn't know that's Android & Java are case-sensitive.

Comment: Sometimes it happens that we ignore some small things. .

Answer (score 3):

Your button calls the method

```
    android:onClick="viewAptoide"
```

While your method name is

```
     public void ViewAptoide
```

Please ensure the naming is consistent otherwise your method is not found

Answer (score 2):

The button's onClick attribute is set to

```
android:onClick="viewAptoide"
```

Change your method name to

```
public void viewAptoide
```

By convention, method names should start with a lowercase character in Java.

Also, since you are accessing the internet using ACTION_VIEW intent, make sure you have the following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: No problem.. Did it work without the internet permission?

Comment: It even work without the internet permission, because I don't want to use a WebView, I just want to open the URL in the default browser.

Comment: Right. Good to know.